# How do I stop the android rating bar from spreading out?

Tags: android, layout

I have a dialog box that contains an EditText, a RatingBar and two Buttons. The rating bar layout_width has been told to wrap_content, but it spreads out the stars to fit nicely in the space the edit text and the buttons make with their layout parameters. This wouldn't be a problem, but I have told it to increment by half-stars. The selected star value is drawn in real-time by chopping the filled in image, allowing for ratings of whatever fraction of star you want, but it seems the spacing is being included, making my half-stars look like third or quarter stars (especially on lower dpi screens where they make the stars much smaller automatically), while whole stars look fine.

Edit: I've noticed that stars to the left show this symptom far less than stars to the right, in all cases. By which I mean, a half-star on the left may be only slightly off, but a half-star on the right will be the furthest out of all. This happens on all phones I've tested. End edit.

I don't have access to the phone it is most obvious on, but you can still see the effect here:
[A picture of a dialog with three full stars, a half star that isn't filled enough, and an empty star http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1071/device2x.png](http://img534.imageshack.us/img534/1071/device2x.png)

The fourth star is not quite filled half way, and it only gets worse on some other phones.

This is my layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp">
    <EditText android:id="@+id/reviewWriteText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="13"/>
    <RatingBar android:id="@+id/reviewStars"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:numStars="5" android:stepSize="0.5" />
    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button android:id="@+id/reviewWriteAccept" android:text="Accept"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <Button android:id="@+id/reviewWriteCancel" android:text="Close"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score -2):

Maybe you can add this to you manifest file

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4"
  android:targetSdkVersion="7"/>
```

Or you should change the padding of rating bar.

Comment: I already have a min=7 and target=7. I tried padding, but that affected the bar as a whole, pushing it sideways, and dropping the last star off the edge. Interestingly, it _didn't_ move the green part (i.e. the filling now appears nowhere near the half mark), so now it looks even worse. I wonder why... Either way, this is a solution that would only work on one phone, as resolutions and dpis are different. Especially when it decides to use different sized stars.